# telegram opens file automatically after download

Tags: telegram

I have a problem with telegram desktop.
**my telegram version is : 1.0.14**
when I start to downloading a file from this messenger for example a winrar file it opens automatically.
 it is awful for my security cause i cant stop the viruses that they send me as this way... .
how can I disable this?! 
and is it a Bug?!

Answer (score 0):

The new version fixes the problem

Comment: The problem is still exists in telegram desktop version 1.1.23.

Answer (score -1):

the issue is currently fixed as of new version to v.4.0 released. Upgrade to latest version.